# Swift switch pattern matching with arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, switch-statement

Curious if there is a way to do the following in Swift.

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3]
let bar = [4, 5, 6]

let value = 5

switch value {
case in foo
    print("5 is in foo")
case in bar
    print("5 is in bar")
default:
    break
}
```

I understand there are other ways I could make this contrived example work such as `case 4, 5, 6:` or not using a switch and instead using `bar.contains(value)` but I'm looking for a solution specifically involving switch pattern matching to an array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could define a custom pattern matching operator
`~=` which takes an array as the "pattern" and a value:

```
func ~=<T : Equatable>(array: [T], value: T) -> Bool {
    return array.contains(value)
}

let foo = [1, 2, 3]
let bar = [4, 5, 6]

let value = 5

switch value {
case foo:
    print("\(value) is in foo")
case bar:
    print("\(value) is in bar")
default:
    break
}
```

Similar operators exist already e.g. for intervals:

```
public func ~=<I : IntervalType>(pattern: I, value: I.Bound) -> Bool
```

Comment: Nice. Wish I'd thought of that.

Answer (score 32):

How about:

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3]
let bar = [4, 5, 6]

let value = 5

switch value {
case _ where foo.contains(value):
    print("\(value) is in foo")
case _ where bar.contains(value):
    print("\(value) is in bar")
default:
    print("\(value) is not in foo or bar")
}
```

Comment: I think this is solution is easier to understand than the accepted answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: This one is also safer to use than accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Vitalii what do you think is less "safe" about the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Martin R Why stop at arrays. All types that conform to the [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocol have a `contains` instance method. The following has the same behavior as your answer, except it works with any type that conforms to `Sequence`.

```swift
func ~=<S : Sequence>(sequence: S, value: S.Element) -> Bool
        where S.Element: Equatable {

    return sequence.contains(value)
}


let items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let iterable = items.makeIterator()

let value = 3

switch value {
    case iterable:
        print("\(value) is contained in iterable")
    default:
        print("\(value) is NOT contained in iterable")
}
```

**However, we can do even better**

I think that `case iterable` is too magical. It doesn't convey the fact that we are testing for `value`'s membership in `iterable`. It would be better if we could write `case containedIn(iterable)`. In fact, this is actually possible:

```swift
public func ~=<T>(pattern: (T) -> Bool, value: T) -> Bool {
    return pattern(value)
}

func containedIn<S : Sequence>(_ sequence: S) -> ((S.Element) -> Bool)
        where S.Element: Equatable {

    return { element in sequence.contains(element) }
}

let arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let setOfNumbers: Set = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let value = 8

switch value {
    case containedIn(arrayOfNumbers):
        print("\(value) is contained in arrayOfNumbers")
    case containedIn(setOfNumbers):
        print("\(value) is contained in setOfNumbers")
    default:
        break
}
```

The only issue with this is that `containedIn` behaves unexpectedly when used outside of the context of a switch statement.